# Wait for file to arrive - SSIS package

Tags: ssis, integration, business-intelligence, flat-file, foreach-loop-container

we have a package that reads text files on an ftp server everyday, however we do not know exactly when the files will be added to the folder on the server, so we have to wait for the files and then fire the package manually. So is there any way to automate the process, so that the job will start whenever files are found?

Comment: An alternative for some kind of ftp listner could be a simple for loop in the SSIS package with a retry machanisme.

Comment: I would advise you to create a division of duties. Much as rvphx suggests, have a dedicated process watch for the file-either through polling (Is it here yet? Try again in N timeunits) or hook wmi events to "hear" the file land. Then launch your SSIS package. This has the benefit of being a reusable approach versus something that gets copied from one package to another. I would also recommend against having an SSIS package poll in perpetuity. It's not designed for that type of work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the SSIS package when the file arrives. In one of my projects, we had a directory listener service that waits for the file to arrive. Once the file arrives, we used to call the SSIS package.

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Use the WMI Event watcher task. That could be of some help. Or, you can simply execute the package every 10 or 30 minutes. A script task can check if the file is available or not, if not, the package exits immediately and if available, execute the DFT.